# Is this an inefficient way to compare data across multiple tables?

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using the following code to first check if a string is located somewhere within a column in my database.  If it is, I am then needing to check if a few additional criteria are met by looking at different parts of the database (can be seen in the code below).  I am not sure if this is an efficient method for doing this or if there is a much simpler way:

(from my Controller)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection sampleKey)
    {
        string code = sampleKey["sampleCode"];
        ViewBag.code = code;
        // Need to check if this code is active
        var order = db.Orders.SingleOrDefault(
            o => o.OrderCode == code
                && o.Active == true);
        if (order == null)
        {
            //Invalid
        }
        else
        {
            var orderIdent = db.OrderDetails.SingleOrDefault(
                p => p.OrderDetailId == order.OrderId);
            var barIdent = db.Drink.SingleOrDefault(
                q => q.EstablishmentsID == orderIdent.DrinksId);
            var barName = db.Establishment.SingleOrDefault(
                r => r.EstablishmentsId == barIdent.EstablishmentsID);
            ViewBag.barId = barName.name;
            ViewBag.sample = order.Email;
            var custProfile = CustomProfile.GetUserProfile();
            if (custProfile.OwnedBar != barName.name)
            {
                //Not a match
            }
            else
            {
                //Match
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Is this something to worry about?  Is there a more efficient way of performing the actions that I am currently performing?  Should I change the first table that is referenced to include data from the table I ultimately compare it to to avoid what seems to be an inefficient way of comparing information from different tables?

Comment: You are certain you can never more than one order that is active with a specific order code?  `.SingleOrDefault()` means that there can only be one, and to return null if there is none or throw an exception if there is more than one.  I wouldn't think you could know that for sure.  Likewise, you only ever have one order detail item?  You do a `.SingleOrDefault()` for that as well.  If there are more than one line items, it will throw an exception.  I also wouldn't think your OrderDetailId would be the same Id as your order, typically you have a unique detail Id per line with an orderid fk

Comment: You have tagged your question with any imaginable tags but you missed the most important one which is the database technology you are using as that's what your question is about. It doesn't really has anything to do with asp.net-mvc

Comment: @MystereMan Actually in this situation there would only ever be one detail id per line with my order id as I intend to have users limited to one purchase per transaction.  From what you say, though, this seems like bad practice.  I suppose I should find a better solution and change the code to reflect that solution.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I apologize, I am still early in the process of teaching myself how to web develop using these technologies.  I am honestly not quite sure what database technology I am using outside of sql.  Would it make sense that the "entity-framework" be the database technology I am using?

Comment: @miscusermandude - And what happens if you decide to allow them to purchase more than one?  You have to go back and change all your code.  But in any event, you missed the first part of my question.  Are you sure there can only ever be one order that is active with a given order code?  if not, then an exception will be thrown.

Comment: @MystereMan Yes, there should be only one order active with any given order code  (think of the code as something someone would use to redeem their purchased product).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the SQL query that gets generated. You can do that by e.g. outputting the queries to the console, which is done by setting `db.Log = Console.Out;`. There should be a similar method to output to the web page in your case. The lazy nature of LINQ makes things difficult to predict.

Other than that, you could make your life much easier if you create foreign key relationships between your tables, i.e. `OrderDetails` has `Orders.OrderId` as a FK. This will allow Entity Framework to generate navigational properties for your database. With them your code would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection sampleKey)
{
    string code = sampleKey["sampleCode"];

    var detail = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderCode == code && o.Active == true)
        .Select(o => new { 
            OrderCode = o.OrderCode,
            BarId = o.Drink.Establishment.Select(n => n.name),
            Sample = o.Email
            })
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (detail != null)
    {
        ViewBag.code = detail.OrderCode;
        ViewBag.barId = detail.BarId;
        ViewBag.sample = detail.Sample;

        var custProfile = CustomProfile.GetUserProfile();
        if (custProfile.OwnedBar == detail.BarId)
        {
            //Match
        }
        else
        {
            //Not a match
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Invalid
    }

    return View();
}
```